# Is there a C# API that can aid in building Google Maps links?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps

For example:

```
OpenUrl(GoogleMaps.Location("my address here"));
```

Would open up Google Maps and input the address as if it were typed right into the search bar on Google Maps itself.

Even better if it was able to do something like:

```
OpenUrl(GoogleMaps.Directions("Starting address", "End Address"));
```

I don't want Google Maps embedded into my application or anything fancy like that.  Url generation would be perfect for my needs.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be: http://gmaps.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Habib I think this may be what I'm looking for.  I'll download it and see how well it works.

Reply with an answer instead of a comment so I can mark you as the solver if it works.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for: 
[Google Maps API for .NET](http://gmaps.codeplex.com/)

For Url generation use: 
**Getting a static map url**

> Static Maps support allows you to get a valid url which you can use,
>   for example, with an  tag.

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow me to get a direct URL to Google Maps itself.  It's giving me the url to the image of the static map (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NuGet in Visual Studio, use http://nuget.org/packages/GoogleMapsApi

Comment: Seem to be running into the same problem as I had with Habib's suggestion.  I can't find any functionality to generate a link to the google maps instead of just a static image.

The Wiki seems to be sorely lacking as well...